# Why can't I select an AliasProperty from WMI?

Tags: powershell, wmi

Given the following:

```
get-wmiobject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -ComputerName SERVER1,SERVER2|select pscomputername,__SERVER
```

Only values for `__SERVER` are returned. However, `PSComputerName` is an `AliasProperty` which points at `__SERVER`. So I expect it to return values as well (the same values as I have in `__SERVER`).

`get-wmiobject win32_networkadapterconfiguration |gm pscomputername,__SERVER` returns the following:

```
Name           MemberType    Definition                       
----           ----------    ----------                       
PSComputerName AliasProperty PSComputerName = __SERVER        
__SERVER       Property      System.String __SERVER {get;set;}
```

I'm certain I've used `PSComputername` in the past, successfully. What am I missing here that's causing it to fail? It's happening with both PowerShell v2 & v3.

Comment: if your  do `get-wmiobject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -ComputerName SERVER1,SERVER2| fl *` the `pscomputername` is populated?

Comment: Yes it is. That's what's so bizarre.

Comment: yes yes... I can just say that i'm on seven with powershell 3.0 and it works.. have you try run `powershell -noprofile` and see if behaviour is the same?

Comment: I'm also on Win7, Powershell 3.0. With `-noprofile` I get the same results. Also with Server 2K8R2, Powershell 2.0 with `-noprofile` - but there, `Get-Member` doesn't show `PSComputerName` at all.

Comment: don't know if is your case but read here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/0901ce0b-8a52-47de-b920-356c5f4ad114/

Comment: That's a great find, and it does seem to match what's happening for me here. `get-wmiobject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -ComputerName SERVER1,SERVER2|%{$_.PSComputername}` produces the expected output. `Select-Object` in this case appears to be buggy.

Comment: Side note: PSComputerName was added in v3, so in v2 it won't show up.

Comment: Are the servers running PS 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before on some websites (see CB's comment)
and also:
[Powershell PSComputerName is empty or blank when selected after invoke-command](http://www.itwalkthru.com/2011/09/powershell-pscomputername-is-empty-or.html)

but there is another issue I came across some time ago and never been mentioned (well not according to my Google search at that time nor now)

Are you trying to query a virtual machine?

because as far as I know and I tried, PsComputerName is absent when you query a VirtualMachine (VMware in my case).

I never found a solution for that or a workaround but I thought it will save you the time for looking one.

If you do find something though I will be more than happy to learn it :)